# Create Dummy Columns for values in Single Pandas Column and Group into single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dummy-variable

I am trying to take a pandas dataframe and perform a pivot like operation on a single column. I want to take multiple rows (grouped by some identification columns) and convert that single column into dummy indicator variables. I know of `pd.get_dummies()` but I want to condense the multiple rows into a single row.

An example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# starting data
d = {'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 
     'name': ['bob','bob','bob','shelby','shelby','jordan','jordan','jordan'],
     'type': ['type1','type2','type4','type1','type6','type5','type8','type2']}
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.head(9))

   ID    name   type
0   1     bob  type1
1   1     bob  type2
2   1     bob  type4
3   2  shelby  type1
4   2  shelby  type6
5   3  jordan  type5
6   3  jordan  type8
7   3  jordan  type2
```

I would like the end result to look like:

```
   ID    name  type1  type2  type4  type5  type6  type8
0   1     bob      1      1      1      0      0      0
1   2  shelby      1      0      0      0      1      0
2   3  jordan      0      1      0      1      0      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go!

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['type'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(['ID','name']).max().reset_index()
```

- `prefix=''` and `prefix_sep=''` avoid adding extra prefix such as `type_type1`, `type_type2` in columns names.
- `groupby(this_columns)` lets you aggregate values from other columns by `this_columns`.
- `max()` on `groupby()` will provide you a maximum of aggregated values, as an example, for `bob`, you will have `type1` values 1,0,0 in dummy format, but you want it 1 if any of it is 1, so `max()` works here.
- `reset_index()` gives your columns `ID` and `name` back which were converted to indices by `groupby()`.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain how ```.max()``` works in this context? Maybe step through exactly what the code is doing?

Comment: Updated it. Let me know if it is still unclear or maybe you wanna try to breakdown the code and explore :)

Comment: Kindly help me with an upvote and accepted answer if my half an hour investment helped you :)

Comment: absolutely. Appreciate the help. I believe this solution is accomplishing what I need

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table` method ([documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html))

```py
df.pivot_table(index=['ID'], columns=['type'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
```

Outputs

```
type type1 type2 type4 type5 type6 type8
ID                                      
1        1     1     1     0     0     0
2        1     0     0     0     1     0
3        0     1     0     1     0     1
```

I wasn't able to get your desired output with a single line method call, you will need to merge both dataframes and keep the columns you wanted.

You will notice that the `pivot_table` method returns a dataframe where the column `ID` is the **index**.